# While running my code in MPI, the root process never executes despite following the correct syntax

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

While trying to execute my code written in C using the MPI Library, I encountered something very odd happening.
My code generates no syntax error yet when I try

```
 mpirun -n 3 ./q4
```

I get this

```
hello
hello
hello
from the other side.
from the other side.
from the other side.
```

It seems to never enter the rank 0 process. I have no idea why this is happening. This code is structurally identical to some other samples that I have writtten (I can provide the entire code if need be)
However, if I were to type in any two random things after the sixth line, I get this

```
1213
123
Enter a length for the string that is divisible by the number of processes Number of vowels 27
```

I don't really know what to do to fix it except that I checked my code for logically errors, which there are none and even if they are, they are much later which means that at least the the code under the first if case should execute.

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
 printf("hello\n");
 int rank,m,size,num;
 MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
 MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
 MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);
 printf("from the other side.\n");
 char str[100];
 if (rank == 0 )
 {
  printf("Enter a length for the string that is divisible by the number of processes ");
  scanf("%d",&m);
  scanf("%s",str);
 }
.
.
```

In case it is relevant, I am running Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: `stdout` is line buffered by default.

Comment: Please try to be more clear in your problem description. "Something strange happening" is a really vague title.

Comment: @Zulan, thanks for your input.  I will keep it in mind.

Comment: tag C, but mpic++ (which is the C++ driver)????

Comment: I couldn't find one for mpic, so I improvised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add some `fflush(stdout);` after the last `printf` to force the text refresh.

When there is no `\n` in `printf` text, the text is not displayed immediately.

So you should write:

```
printf("Enter a length for the string that is divisible by the number of processes ");
fflush(stdout);
scanf("%d",&m);
....
```

Or simpler:

```
puts("Enter a length for the string that is divisible by the number of processes ");
scanf("%d",&m);
....
```

The `puts` is to print a message on a line (it creates a new line). And it's not buffered.

Comment: [pappuyadav:28670] *** Process received signal ***
[pappuyadav:28670] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[pappuyadav:28670] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[pappuyadav:28670] Failing at address: 0x7fff31a8b000
[pappuyadav:28670] [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x3ef20)[0x7f7bcc028f20]
[pappuyadav:28670] [ 1] ./q4(+0xfd4)[0x560f23a80fd4]
[pappuyadav:28670] [ 2] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe7)[0x7f7bcc00bb97]
[pappuyadav:28670] [ 3] ./q4(+0xb5a)[0x560f23a80b5a]
[pappuyadav:28670] *** End of error message ***

Comment: That is what I got.

Comment: I am sorry. I got it.

Comment: Even with a flush, that doesn't mean that MPI has to flush its IO as well, does it?

Comment: [`fflush(stdout);`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fflush) will only flush the standard output. Other MPI I/O won't be affected.

Answer (score -1):

In case anyone ever reads this in the future, this is to add to what Matthieu said.
The code should be like this

```
 if (rank == 0 )
 {
  printf("Enter a length for the string that is divisible by the number of processes \n");
    fflush(stdout);
.
.
.
```